# How to give node sillouhette when behind wall in Godot

Tags: shaders, godot, first-person-shooter, gdscript

I am working on a boss-rush fps game. I want it to be like the eye of cthulu fight from terraria, with the enemy flying towards you and then turning around to try again if it misses. However, in order for that to work, the enemy must be visible when they are under the ground. How could I accomplish this?

Comment: There is no image and link to the post. Guess you want us to know ;-)

Comment: The image was working a few days ago. I don't know what happened. I think the site removed the image, when I looked it up I couldn't find it.

Comment: I couldn't see the image when you first posted this question, but I assumed you'd edit to fix it in a minute or two so I didn't mention it at the time.